Button text color adopts background color after upgrading to Angular Material 18
After upgrading to Angular and Angular Material version 18.0.0, the button text color incorrectly takes on the button's background color, making the text unreadable. This issue did not exist in version 17.0.0.
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

@import './color.scss';

// @include mat.all-component-themes(get-light-theme($blue-theme));

$kids-theme: mat.m2-define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: mat.m2-define-palette($cyan-theme),
      accent: mat.m2-define-palette($yellow-theme),
    ),
  )
);

@include mat.all-component-themes($kids-theme);`

The button text color should remain distinct from the background color as specified in the theme settings.
The button text color adopts the button's background color, making the text difficult to read.
Stackblitz link

I am not sure how this worked with Angular Material v17, but your palettes are invalid. For example, take a look at your yellow palette:
$yellow-theme: (
  50: #fcf1e0,
  100: #f7dcb3,
  200: #f2c580,
  300: #edad4d,
  400: #e99c26,
  500: #e58a00,
  600: #e28200,
  700: #de7700,
  800: #da6d00,
  900: #d35a00,
  A100: #fffcfb,
  A200: #ffdcc8,
  A400: #ffbb95,
  A700: #ffab7b,
  contrast: (
    50: #fcf1e0,
    100: #d35a00,
    200: #da6d00,
    300: #de7700,
    400: #e28200,
    500: #e58a00,
    600: #e99c26,
    700: #edad4d,
    800: #f2c580,
    900: #f7dcb3,
    A100: #fffcfb,
    A200: #ffdcc8,
    A400: #ffbb95,
    A700: #ffab7b,
  ),
);

In the contrast map, you need to choose the foreground / contrast color (usually black or white) with the best contrast to the given hue color, see the theming docs. However you are choosing the same or a very similar color which you already use for the background again, which makes the text unreadable. The palette should look more like the following:
$yellow-theme: (
  50: #fcf1e0, // here you need to set the hues of your desired color
  100: #f7dcb3,
  200: #f2c580,
  300: #edad4d,
  400: #e99c26,
  500: #e58a00,
  600: #e28200,
  700: #de7700,
  800: #da6d00,
  900: #d35a00,
  A100: #fffcfb,
  A200: #ffdcc8,
  A400: #ffbb95,
  A700: #ffab7b,
  contrast: (
    50: #000000, // <- here you need to choose white or black
    100: #000000, // based on what gives better contrast
    200: #000000,
    300: #000000,
    400: #000000,
    500: #000000,
    600: #ffffff,
    700: #ffffff,
    800: #ffffff,
    900: #ffffff,
    A100: #000000,
    A200: #000000,
    A400: #000000,
    A700: #000000,
  ),
);

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a3pvnb?file=src%2Fcolor.scss

The solution you provided does not work. This issue is not related to a color palette; it originates from Angular Material.

It does work, I have attached the working StackBlitz.

You provided me with solutions that work, but I need the theme color palette to be adapted for dark mode, using contrasting colors. In my Stackblitz project, I demonstrated how to use a contrasting color palette for dark mode.
my application live link
for a better understanding you

@DikshitPatel You are clearly doing something wrong. Contrast colors should be used for contrast, not for dark theme. I don't know why and how this worked with Angular v17, but I strongly believe this was purely by chance. Angular Material has never supported this. You can implement dark theme by applying multiple themes to your app, see the theming docs.

Updated stackblitz with working light & dark mode (I added mat-app-background for better visibility): https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r4yu3i?file=src%2Fcolor.scss. Note that again I only needed to fix the nonsense contrast colors.
